# Finding terminal points for vector

Tags: vectors

I have a problem on vector.

Vectors $ \vec a= (2, 4) ,\vec b = (−1, 2),$ and $\vec c = (c_1, c_2)$ all have the initial point at the origin, what are the coordinates of their terminal points?

Can you direct me on how to find terminal points for vector $\vec c$?
Thanks.
Aaron

Comment: Vectors don’t have “initial” and “terminal” points—they have *magnitude* and *direction*. It’s line segments that have two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same as with $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$: the $x$-component of the vector tells you by how much you move on the $x$-axis, and the $y$-component tells you by how much you move on the $y$-axis. Since you start from the origin, that should tell you the answer.

If it doesn't, try with other examples of $c_1$ and $c_2$ and you'll see :)

Comment: I understand terminal points for a (2, 4) and b (-1, 2). But c I am not sure. Is it c (c1, ,c2)? Not sure this makes sense.

Comment: Yes it is. For $\vec{a}$, you move $2$ units on the $x$-axis, and 4 on the $y$-axis. So you land on $(2,4)$. Same with $\vec{c}$: you move $c_1$ units on the $x$-axis and $c_2$ units on the right axis, so you land on $(c_1,c_2)$.

Comment: Because all 3 vectors start at origin, I tried to add vectors a and b to get c e.g. c (2-1, 4+2) -> c (1, 6). However, apparently this seems to be incorrect. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you think it is incorrect? Addition for vectors is indeed defined component-wise, you do have a + b = (1, 6)

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: @LisaLevi Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right) $. Thanks.

Comment: @LisaLevi I repeat my last comment: Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$. Thanks. It would show that you appreciate the effort of the people who read your question and answer it.

Comment: I have marked. Thank you so much!